# pro-commutative group schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, group-schemes

When $k$ is field, Demazure and Gabriel defined and worked with the category of commutative pro-algebraic groups over $k$. In their book, they proved that $Ext^n(\varprojlim G_i, H)= \varinjlim Ext^n(G_i,H)$ (Chap.5, cor. 3.9), the Ext is taken within the category of commutative pro-algebraic groups. When working with general base $S$, I am aware that the category of commuatative group schemes over $S$ needs not be abelian. But do we have similar construction of the pro-category here? More importantly (this is really the question I concern) do we have the isomorphism  $Ext^n(\varprojlim G_i, H)= \varinjlim Ext^n(G_i,H)$ in general?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Oh no.. sorry for the typos. edited.